# Merging the cell using button in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In handsontable, we can merge the cell by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd>. But I want to merge the cell in handsontable using a button. As I am not good in coding, any suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 <script> 
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        var container = document.getElementById('mainTable'), hot;

        hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(50, 26),
            minRows: 5,
            minCols: 6,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            mergeCells: true,
            currentRowClassName: 'current Row',
            currentColClassName: 'current Col'

        });
        hot.selectCell(2,2);

        function bindDumpButton() {
            if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
                return;
            }

            Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {

                var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

                if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
                    var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
                    var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
                    var hot = window[instance];
                    console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
                }
            });
        }
        bindDumpButton();

     });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Please show us some of your code.

Comment: <script>
/* global mergeCells */

$(document).ready(function() {
    
   $('button').click(function() {
       mergeCells: true;
   });
});
</script>